# Click on a Pin to get to another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I currently have a map view controller which sets a pin to a location. When clicking on the pin I would like this to go to another view controller however this does not do anything when it is ran. Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class mapquiz: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.5206608, -1.8913687)
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 1500, 1500), animated: true)

        let pin = PinAnnotation(title: "Birmingham", subtitle:"Second largest city" , coordinate: location)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)

        func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
            if(segue.identifier == "newView") {
                var UserViewController = (segue.destination as! UserViewController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use delegate method - didSelectAnnotationView and do further manipulations

Answer (score 1):

The `MKMapViewDelegate` has a method called `mapView(_:didSelect:)`. You can perform a segue in this method. Also, you should override the `prepare(for:sender:)`, NOT inside the `viewDidLoad()`.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class mapquiz: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.delegate = self

        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33.5206608, -1.8913687)
        mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 1500, 1500), animated: true)

        let pin = PinAnnotation(title: "Birmingham", subtitle:"Second largest city" , coordinate: location)
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newView" {
            let userViewController = segue.destination as! UserViewController
            // TODO: something
        }
    }
}

extension mapquiz: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "newView", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about that error? Are you using Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: Hi this is now working thanks however when I click the pin it takes me straight to the next view controller however I want it so when I click the pin it shows the title and subtitle then when I click this is takes me to the view controller? Thanks